# Getting AdView to actually show up

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem with google adview... it's not showing up.  I dug around a for a while and saw that people where having issues with padding, so I removed the padding and still no luck.

Here is my relevant manifest data:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

    <meta-data 
        android:value="a14d91b10f12454" 
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/greygradient">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2" android:padding="15dp">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageviewdetail"></ImageView>
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/textviewdetailname" android:textSize="18dp"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Snip -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Sign Up!" android:id="@+id/buttondetailsubmit" android:layout_margin="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" ></Button>
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/googleads" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the code that is running the ad:

```
AdView ad = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.googleads);
ad.setEnabled(true);
ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d91b10f12454");
AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
r.setTesting(true);
ad.loadAd(r);
```

In my LogCat, it shows that I am recieving ads.  And in AdMob admin panel you can see that there have been successful requests made.. but I cannot get the stupid view to actually show up!

Anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't adding the AdView to your layout when you create the new AdView with

```
ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d91b10f12454");
```

You should remove the AdView from the xml and do this.

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d91b10f12454");
parent.addView(ad);
AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
r.setTesting(true);
ad.loadAd(r);
```

Comment: that did it. Thanks!  Any reason as to why I cannot use the XML way?

Comment: I'm sure you can but I don't think it's documented on how to specify the publisher id through xml and you can only specify it through the constructor.

Comment: yea i noticed there wasnt any 'setPublisherId'.... which seems really silly... thanks for the help though.

Comment: My problem was a little different. I was following the google doc verbatum, and it wouldnt display that adds. I used your code and it works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Example of how to set up a banner ad through xml:

**attrs.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="adSize">
            <enum name="BANNER" value="1" />
            <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2" />
            <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3" />
            <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="adUnitId" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**layout**:
Add to the layout 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/APP_PACKAGE_NAME"`
(Where APP_PACKAGE_NAME is your app's package name)
and then:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:adUnitId="YOUR_ADMOD_ID" 
app:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good guid for Banner XML to Android Google AdMob Ads available at : [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html)