# Trying to add AdView in android game

Tags: java, android, ads, adview

I am making an android game that i want to have ads on(the free version, not on the paid one), but i cant get it to work properly, it displays an ad-looking rectangle that says in red: You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges. But i got that. Please help me and thanks SO much in advance! Take a look at my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mysoftwaremobileapps.ParachuteHunterLite"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ParachutehunterActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation">

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".GameScreenActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".playerLostMessageActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mysoftwaremobileapps.ParachuteHunterLite.SubmitScoreActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity><activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".AdActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"><meta-data android:value="Number" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" /></activity>



</application>

</manifest>
```

Code to add AdView:

```
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout3);
    AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14d91b10f12454");
    parent.addView(ad);
    AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
    ad.loadAd(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the name, try

```
android:name="com.google.ads.AddActivity"
```

If that doesn't work, here is another question about AdsActivity that might help (which is where I got the above line):

[Getting AdView to actually show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462937/getting-adview-to-actually-show-up)